# VS2015 solution build giving compile error

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, dependencies

I've been battling with a bizarre compilation error that I've been getting when running VS2015.  The error is that when I compile (rebuild) a solution (it's a large solution, with 96 projects), I get a compilation error.  The error is:

> 70>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyBase,
>   Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   70>I:\WS\Main\Common\MyBase\MyBase\BaseApplication.cs(1,7,1,10):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyProject' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, the first thing that I did was try to compile `MyBase`, and it compiles fine.  I then individually compiled (rebuild) various groups of projects, until it finally errored when trying to compile the first project that used MyBase, giving a slightly different error:

> 44>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyBase, Configuration: Debug
>   Any CPU ------
>
> 43>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'I:\WS\Main\Common\MyBase\MyBase\bin\Debug\MyBase.dll' could not be
>   found

The next thing that I tried was an MSBuild on the command line of the entire solution - which worked.

Finally, returning to VS2015, i tried doing a rebuild, and then a build, and the solution didn't error.

Looking at the numbers in the build, it looks to me like it is executing some of the build steps out of synch (44 before 43).  Is this possible?  Is there some kind of asynchronous build that has crept into VS and started causing this behaviour.  I've double and triple checked the dependencies, and they seem fine to me.

Comment: Seems like you did not define your project dependencies and build order correctly. Or you have circular references (ie project x depends on project y and vice versa).

Comment: How to setup those project dependencies.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165133.aspx

Comment: I don't have circular dependencies (in fact, I don't believe that you can if you have project dependencies).  I've checked, and the build order looks correct to me, that is, the projects build in the order that I would expect.  What I did try was to remove the reference from the project that was erroring and then re-add the project reference; which made it work.  However, nothing in the solution or the build order was changed!

Comment: A circular dependency is technically possible, but it has the advantage of never being able to build.  So that is not it, MSBuild somehow did not calculate the project dependencies correctly.  The question does not give any hint why that might be.  Just help it, right-click the project that doesn't build > Build dependencies > Project dependencies > tick MyBase.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 supports parallel compiles. If some of your projects depend on each other you have to set up project dependencies. You can do this with the **project dependencies** menu point in the **project** menu. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx) for details.